# Fuzzy pattern matching from emails in C#

Tags: c#, regex, machine-learning, fuzzy-search

I'm looking for a way to extract bits of data from emails. I'm primarily looking at subject lines and the email body, and extracting customer and order reference numbers.

Imagine I'm a company where customers can email an info@mydomain.com and they might add a specific customer number or order reference in the subject line or body of the email. However, they might not always provide these references in the optimal format. I want to extract the data out, and return a probability of how likely the data is valid.

Is there some kind of technique I can use to attempt to scan an email and return a probable customer number and or order reference with a degree of probability (a bit like Bayesian spam filtering)?

I was considering some kind of regular expression engine, but that seemed too rigid. I was also looking at [NUML.net](https://github.com/sethjuarez/numl) and wondering if it could help me, but I'm a little out of my depth, since I'm not entirely sure what I need. I've come across the Levenshtein algorithm, but that seems to be matching two fixed strings, rather than a fixed string and a pattern.

I'm imagining an API that look a little like this:

```
// emailMessage is a Mandrill inbound object, in case anybody wonders
EmailScanResult results = EmailScanner.Scan(emailMessage, new {ScanType.CustomerNo, ScanType.OrderReference});
foreach (var result in results)
{
    var scanType = result.Type; // I.e. ScanType.CustomerNo
    var score = result.Score; // e.g. 1.2
    var value = result.Value; // CU-233454345-2321
}
```

Possible inputs for this are varied; E.g. For the same customer number:

- DF-232322-AB2323
- df-232322-AB2323
- 232322-ab2323
- 232322AB2323

What kinds of algorithms would be useful for such a task? Are there any recommended .NET libraries for this, and do you know of any appropriate examples?

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you could use a regular expression with no problem. For example, with the input samples you gave, you could use a regex like:

> ([A-Z|a-z]{2,2}-){0,1}\d{6,6}-{0,1}\d{4,4}

- The first part gets the *DF-* or *df-*, which may or may not occur: **([A-Z|a-z]{2,2}-){0,1}**
- The second part gets the first group of digits: **\d{6,6}**
- Then, we say that it could have a dash: **\-{0,1}**
- Finally, we get the last group of digits: **\d{4,4}**

This would cover the values you provided as sample, but you also could write other expressions to fetch other values.

Or, maybe, you could use something like [Lucene.net](http://lucenenet.apache.org/). From what I know, this could help you too.
http://pt.slideshare.net/nitin_stephens/lucene-basics 
http://jsprunger.com/getting-started-with-lucene-net/